# how to web scrape number of citations per paper per year for an author on google scholar?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-scholar

I would like to draw a bar chart of how the h-index of a google-scholar author changes over each year. To compute that, I would need number of citations per paper per year and compute h-index per year.

I've managed to get the graph on the author profile page. Take Albert Einstein's google scholar as an example https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ&hl=en, I obtained the citation counts graph per year on the right, but that's not correct. What I truly want is when you click on a paper, there is a Total citations by year graph. I use BeautifulSoup and selenium package in Python. My biggest difficulty right now is:
If you check the html code of an author, the content of each paper is hidden, how to click through every paper and access the total-citations-by-year-per-paper graph?

Here is what I did for the graph on the right

```py
def get_citation_by_year(url):
    s = soup(str(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()), 'lxml')
    print(s)
    #print(s.title.text) #whose google scholar is this?
    years = list(map(int, [i.text for i in s.find_all('span', {'class':'gsc_g_t'})]))
    citation_number = list(map(int, [i.text for i in s.find_all('span', {'class':'gsc_g_al'})]))
    final_chart_data = dict(zip(years, citation_number))
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': years, 'Cited_By': citation_number})
    return(df)
```

Click the showmore botton to display max articles:

```
def get_citation_byarticle_byyear(url):
    #quote_page is an URL of google scholar page of a specific author
    quote_page = url
    page = urlopen(quote_page)
    # Click Show more 
    chrome_options = Options()  
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"/Users/upcrown/Desktop/chromedriver") #need to download ChromeDriver, http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)

    python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsc_bpf_more"]')
    python_button.click() #click fhsu link

    time.sleep(5)
    # Selenium hands the page source to Beautiful Soup
    s = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

    year = list(map(str, [i.text for i in s.find_all('span', {'class': 'gsc_a_h gsc_a_hc gs_ibl'})])) ##string not int because some are ''

    #find the paper
    #paper = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "gsc_a_at"})
    paper = list(map(str, [i.text for i in s.find_all('a', {'class': 'gsc_a_at'})]))
    #find the citations 
    #citations = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class":"gsc_a_ac gs_ibl"})
    citations = list(map(str, [i.text for i in s.find_all('a', {'class': 'gsc_a_ac gs_ibl'})]))
```

Other tools tried: R "scholar" package, don't have citation counts per paper per year, only has citation counts per year. 
Windows application: Publish or Perish(same problem). 
Scopus API (not having full lists of all articles of an author as google scholar)

Comment: Are you also intending on exhausting the _show more_ button at the bottom or only working with articles present on initial page load (or some max # articles)?

Comment: Hi @QHarr, I need the max # of articles but already got that part done by clicking the showmore botton in my code:     python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsc_bpf_more"]')
    python_button.click() #click

Comment: There is a painful way I think which it that you can extract the strings used to make up the urls which provide each data point (the years are concatenated into a string for the url and the rest of the variable info for the url string is in the page)

Comment: Thank you , you are right. I guess my question for that approach is how to click through every article to access the pop-up window, because there is no "button" like the "show more" for article link.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party solution like SerpApi to access the "pop-up" or citation when you click on one of the articles. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "SECRET_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "hl": "en",
  "author_id": "qc6CJjYAAAAJ",
  "citation_id": "qc6CJjYAAAAJ:qyhmnyLat1gC",
  "view_op": "view_citation"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
"citation": {
  "title": "Rosen (1935)",
  "authors": "A Einstein, B Podolsky",
  "publication_date": "1964",
  "journal": "Physical Review",
  "volume": "47",
  "pages": "777",
  "total_citations": {
    "cited_by": {
      "total": 20216,
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=8174092782678430881,4810886029029668500,2204829022686080230&as_sdt=5",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=8174092782678430881%2C4810886029029668500%2C2204829022686080230&engine=google_scholar&hl=en",
      "cites_id": "8174092782678430881,4810886029029668500,2204829022686080230"
    },
    "table": [
      {
        "year": 1983,
        "citations": 68
      },
      {
        "year": 1984,
        "citations": 62
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  "scholar_articles": [
    {
      "title": "Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?",
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&cluster=8174092782678430881&btnI=1&hl=en",
      "authors": "A Einstein, B Podolsky, N Rosen - Physical review, 1935",
      "cited_by": {
        "total": 20195,
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=8174092782678430881&as_sdt=5",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=8174092782678430881&engine=google_scholar&hl=en",
        "cites_id": "8174092782678430881"
      },
      "related_pages_link": {
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&q=related:odSh4BM2cHEJ:scholar.google.com/"
      },
      "versions": {
        "total": 96,
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cluster=8174092782678430881",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?cluster=8174092782678430881&engine=google_scholar&hl=en",
        "cluster_id": "8174092782678430881"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Podolsky B Rosen N 1935",
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&cluster=4810886029029668500&btnI=1&hl=en",
      "authors": "A Einstein - Phys. Rev",
      "cited_by": {
        "total": 48,
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=4810886029029668500&as_sdt=5",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=4810886029029668500&engine=google_scholar&hl=en",
        "cites_id": "4810886029029668500"
      },
      "related_pages_link": {
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&q=related:lPYzr1qzw0IJ:scholar.google.com/"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "RosenN",
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&cluster=2204829022686080230&btnI=1&hl=en",
      "authors": "PB EinsteinA - Canquantum mechanical …",
      "cited_by": {
        "total": 16,
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=2204829022686080230&as_sdt=5",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=2204829022686080230&engine=google_scholar&hl=en",
        "cites_id": "2204829022686080230"
      },
      "related_pages_link": {
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&q=related:5uysf1AgmR4J:scholar.google.com/"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Page screenshot:

[image]

You can check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-citation) for more details.

Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.